# JavaFX scene is not changing when root gets updated

Tags: java, javafx, scene

I am trying to make a snake JavaFX game. The scene is a board that consists of 25x25 images. For now, I just want to make the snake go to the right before I add userInput. The first scene is loading from Controller.java and then in Main.java, I am calling run_game() method (inside controller.java) which changes the scene every second. The issue is that the first scene shows up but the scene does not get updated. There is no error, the program just keeps running till I stop it.

Here are the classes:-

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Main extends Application {
    public Controller game;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Snake Game");
        game = new Controller();
        primaryStage.setScene(game.scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    game.run_game();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },0,1000);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }


}
```

Controller.java

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Controller {
    public Snake snake;
    public Board board;
    public Food food;
    public Movement move;
    public static GridPane grid_pane;
    public Scene scene;


    // Creating all the necessary instances of snake game
    public Controller() throws InterruptedException {
        food = new Food();
        grid_pane = new GridPane();
        //assigning a random food position to the food apple
        assign_random_position_to_food();
        snake = new Snake(food);
        board = new Board();
        move = new Movement(snake);
        board.generateBoard(food.row, food.col, snake);

        Parent root = grid_pane;
        scene = new Scene(root, Board.BOARDHEIGHT,Board.BOARDWIDTH);


    }

    public void run_game() throws InterruptedException {

        snake = move.move_RIGHT();

        scene.setRoot( grid_pane);
    }
    public void assign_board_to_grid(){
        for ( int row = 0; row < board.board.length; ++row)
            for( int col = 0; col < board.board[row].length; ++col )
                grid_pane.add(board.board[row][col], row, col, 1, 1);
    }
    public void assign_random_position_to_food(){
        food.RandomPosition();
    }

}
```

Board.java

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class Board {

    public static int BOARDHEIGHT = 500;
    public static int BOARDWIDTH = 500;
    public static int BLOCKHEIGHT = 20;
    public static int BLOCKWIDTH = 20;
    public static int TOTAL_BLOCKS_ROW = BOARDHEIGHT/ BLOCKHEIGHT;
    public static int TOTAL_BLOCKS_COL = BOARDWIDTH/ BLOCKWIDTH;
    public ImageView[][] board;
    public Image black_square;
    public Image apple;
    public Image snake_dot;
    public GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

    public void assign_images(){
        try{
            apple = new Image("images/apple.png");
            snake_dot = new Image("images/dot.png");
            black_square = new Image("images/black_square.png");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: related to the address of images");
        }
    }

    public Board(){

        assign_images();

        //initializing the board
        board = new ImageView[TOTAL_BLOCKS_ROW][TOTAL_BLOCKS_COL];
    }

    public void generateBoard(int food_x, int food_y, Snake snake_body) {

        for(int row=0; row< TOTAL_BLOCKS_ROW; row++){
            for(int col=0; col< TOTAL_BLOCKS_COL; col++){

                if(row == food_x && col == food_y)// && check if it is not on snake body)
                    board[row][col] = new ImageView(apple);
                else if( snake_body.is_snake_present(row,col) && col != 0)
                    board[row][col] =  new ImageView(snake_dot);
                else
                    board[row][col] = new ImageView(black_square);

                // Setting the size of each block on the scene
                board[row][col].setFitHeight(BLOCKHEIGHT);
                board[row][col].setFitWidth(BLOCKWIDTH);

                Controller.grid_pane.add(board[row][col], row, col, 1 ,1);
            }
        }

    }





}
```

Movement.java

```
public class Movement {
    public Snake snake;
    public static int new_y_position;
    public static int new_x_position;
    public Movement(Snake snake){
        this.snake = snake;
    }
    public Snake move_RIGHT(){
        new_x_position = snake.getHead_x() + 1;
        new_y_position = snake.getHead_y();

        if(!check_if_snake_is_in_bounds(new_x_position, new_y_position))
            return null;

        //System.out.println(new_x_position);

        snake.setHead_x(new_x_position);
        Block b;
        for (int i = snake.snake.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i){
            b = snake.snake.get(i);
            b.setX(b.getX() + 1);
            snake.snake.set(i,b);
        }
       // System.out.println(snake);

        return snake;
    }

    public Snake move_LEFT(){
        new_x_position = snake.getHead_x() - 1;
        new_y_position = snake.getHead_y();

        if(!check_if_snake_is_in_bounds(new_x_position, new_y_position))
            return null;

        //snake is inbounds update position
        snake.setHead_x(new_x_position);
        Block b;
        for (int i = snake.snake.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i){
            b = snake.snake.get(i);
            b.setX(b.getX() - 1);
            snake.snake.set(i,b);
        }
        System.out.println(snake);


        return snake;
    }
    public Snake move_UP(){
        new_x_position = snake.getHead_x();
        new_y_position = snake.getHead_y() + 1;

        if(!check_if_snake_is_in_bounds(new_x_position, new_y_position))
            return null;

        //snake is inbounds update position
        snake.setHead_y(new_y_position);
        Block b;
        for (int i = snake.snake.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i){
            b = snake.snake.get(i);
            b.setY(b.getY() + 1);
            snake.snake.set(i,b);
        }
        System.out.println(snake);

        return snake;
    }
    public Snake move_DOWN(){
        new_x_position = snake.getHead_x();
        new_y_position = snake.getHead_y() - 1;

        if(!check_if_snake_is_in_bounds(new_x_position, new_y_position))
            return null;
        //snake is inbounds update position
        snake.setHead_y(new_y_position);
        Block b;
        for (int i = snake.snake.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i){
            b = snake.snake.get(i);
            b.setY(b.getY() - 1);
            snake.snake.set(i,b);
        }
        System.out.println(snake);

        return snake;
    }

    public boolean check_if_snake_is_in_bounds(int x, int y){

        return x >= 0 && x <= Board.TOTAL_BLOCKS_COL && y >= 0 && y <= Board.TOTAL_BLOCKS_ROW;
    }
}
```

Snake.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Snake {
    public ArrayList<Block> snake = new ArrayList<>();
    public int snake_size = snake.size();
    int head_x, head_y;

    public Snake(Food food){
        // initializes a snake head location on board and stores it in a list.
        do{
            head_x = (int) (Math.random()*Board.TOTAL_BLOCKS_COL);
            head_y = (int) (Math.random()*Board.TOTAL_BLOCKS_ROW);
        }while(food.getRow() == head_x || food.getCol() == head_y);

        //inserting head and a block in snake arraylist
        snake.add(new Block(head_x, head_y));
        snake.add(new Block(head_x - 1, head_y));

    }

    // Adds new body part when snake eats an apple.
    public void add_snake_body() {
        snake.add( retrieve_new_block_position() );
    }
    // gets new snake body part position.
    public Block retrieve_new_block_position(){
        int last_block_x = snake.get(snake_size - 1).getX();
        int last_block_y = snake.get(snake_size - 1).getY();
        int second_last_block_x = snake.get(snake_size - 2).getX();
        int second_last_block_y = snake.get(snake_size - 2).getY();
        int new_block_x;
        int new_block_y;

        if(second_last_block_x == last_block_x){
            new_block_x = last_block_x;
            new_block_y = last_block_y - 1;
        }
        else{
            new_block_x = last_block_x - 1;
            new_block_y = last_block_y;
        }
         return new Block(new_block_x, new_block_y);
    }

    //checks if a position is occupied by a snake body part.
    public boolean is_snake_present(int row, int col){
        int index = 0;
        int snake_curr_block_x;
        int snake_curr_block_y;

        while(index < snake.size()){
            snake_curr_block_x = snake.get(index).getX();
            snake_curr_block_y = snake.get(index).getY();

            if( snake_curr_block_x == row && snake_curr_block_y == col)
                return true;
            index++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //GETTER & SETTER METHODS
    public ArrayList<Block> getSnake() {
        return snake;
    }

    public int getHead_x() {
        return head_x;
    }

    public void setHead_x(int head_x) {
        this.head_x = head_x;
    }

    public int getHead_y() {
        return head_y;
    }

    public void setHead_y(int head_y) {
        this.head_y = head_y;
    }
}
```

Food.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Food {
    int row;
    int col;

    public Food(){

    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public void setCol(int col) {
        this.col = col;
    }

    public void RandomPosition(){
        this.row = (int) (Math.random() * Board.TOTAL_BLOCKS_ROW);
        this.col = (int) (Math.random() * Board.TOTAL_BLOCKS_COL);
        System.out.println(this.row+" -food- "+ this.col);
        //need to check if it clashes with the snake body................

    }
}
```

Block.java

```
public class Block {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Block(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use java util for background tasks, instead use fx concurrency support - and java naming conventions, please

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you for that tip. I used Platform.runLater() when I change the scene and I am able to change scenes now. Thank you again.